# Abstractions provided by the operating system

Tags: c++, c, architecture, operating-system, abstraction

In the book "Computer System: A Programmer's Perspective", it says that "files are abstractions for I/O devices, virtual memory is an abstraction for both the main memory and disk I/O devices, and processes are abstractions for the processor, main memory, and I/O devices.". I don't really understand that. Can anyone please give me some easy-to-understand explanation ?

Comment: What the OS presents to you as a file is really a pattern of bits on a disk (assuming that bits are "real", of course, but if you don't you're leaving CS for EE :). Files are an abstract, logical way of organizing these bit patterns.

Answer (score 0):

The whole point about abstractions is that they don't exist physically, they are just conceptual. So a storage device is just a bunch of storage blocks, but we impose the abstract concept of directories and files as a way of organising all these blocks of storage into something useful. Each block on the storage device has no way of "knowing" that it belongs to a particular file.

Similarly for the other examples, e.g. processes don't physically exist - the CPU is just executing code, but we organise the code and the way it is executed conceptually into processes and threads, etc - the CPU has no "knowledge" of processes, it's just a code executing machine.